# How can I convert yolo weights to tflite file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite, yolo

I will use yolo weights in android so I plan to convert yolo weights file to tflite file.

I use this code in anaconda prompt because I downloaded keras library in env.

```
activate env   
python convert.py yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights model_data/yolo.h5
```

Finally, it did.Saved Keras model to `model_data/yolo.h5`

And I'm going to convert this h5 file to `tflite` file in jupyter notebook with this code.

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./yolo/yolo.h5", compile=False)
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("keras_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

But this error occurs.

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-3-964a59978091> in <module>()

  1 model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./yolo/yolo.h5", compile=False)

  2 converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)

----> 3 tflite_model = converter.convert()

  4 open("keras_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)



~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\lite\python\lite.py in convert(self)

426         raise ValueError(

427             "None is only supported in the 1st dimension. Tensor '{0}' has "

--> 428             "invalid shape '{1}'.".format(_get_tensor_name(tensor), shape_list))

429       elif shape_list and shape_list[0] is None:

430         # Set the batch size to 1 if undefined.



ValueError: None is only supported in the 1st dimension. Tensor 'input_1' has invalid shape '[None, None, None, 3]'.
```

How can I fix it?

---

our model summary is

Model: "model_1"

---

## Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to

input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, None, None,  0

---

conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, None, None, 3 864         input_1[0][0]

---

batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, None, None, 3 128         conv2d_1[0][0]

---

leaky_re_lu_1 (LeakyReLU)       (None, None, None, 3 0           batch_normalization_1[0][0]

---

zero_padding2d_1 (ZeroPadding2D (None, None, None, 3 0           leaky_re_lu_1[0][0]

---

conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, None, None, 6 18432       zero_padding2d_1[0][0]

---

batch_normalization_2 (BatchNor (None, None, None, 6 256         conv2d_2[0][0]

---

leaky_re_lu_2 (LeakyReLU)       (None, None, None, 6 0           batch_normalization_2[0][0]

---

conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, None, None, 3 2048        leaky_re_lu_2[0][0]

---

.
.
.
.

---

batch_normalization_65 (BatchNo (None, None, None, 5 2048        conv2d_66[0][0]

---

batch_normalization_72 (BatchNo (None, None, None, 2 1024        conv2d_74[0][0]

---

leaky_re_lu_58 (LeakyReLU)      (None, None, None, 1 0           batch_normalization_58[0][0]

---

leaky_re_lu_65 (LeakyReLU)      (None, None, None, 5 0           batch_normalization_65[0][0]

---

leaky_re_lu_72 (LeakyReLU)      (None, None, None, 2 0           batch_normalization_72[0][0]

---

conv2d_59 (Conv2D)              (None, None, None, 2 261375      leaky_re_lu_58[0][0]

---

conv2d_67 (Conv2D)              (None, None, None, 2 130815      leaky_re_lu_65[0][0]

---

## conv2d_75 (Conv2D)              (None, None, None, 2 65535       leaky_re_lu_72[0][0]

Total params: 62,001,757
Trainable params: 61,949,149
Non-trainable params: 52,608

---

Comment: can you post what is the output model.summary()

Comment: In tflite, None ony accepted for `batc_size`. So you need to provide size of your input image.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're getting the H5 file of the Keras YOLO model. For TFLite models, you'll require a model that has a definite input shape like `( 256 , 256 , 3 )`. Also, for an H5 model, you can't modify the input shape after the model is saved. So, you can take these measures,

- Go to the file where the model and its layers are instantiated, modify the input shape there. Retrain the model using that fixed input size.
- Use the [TFLite Object Detection API](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/how-to-train-your-own-custom-model-with-tensorflow-object-detection-api-and-deploy-it-into-android-aeacab7fa76f). This has an [Android sample app](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android) too.
- Train the model using DarkNet as mentioned [here](https://www.tooploox.com/blog/card-detection-using-yolo-on-android).
- If you're trying to detect one of the 20 classes present in the PASCAL, use this [model](https://modelzoo.co/model/android-yolo).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing so:

1. Convert Darknet weights (`.weights`) to TensorFlow frozen graph format (`.pb`).
2. Convert this `.pb` file to tflite.

This process is simpler. I have documented some 3-4 methods to convert Darknet to TensorFlow. Please find them [here](https://medium.com/@prashantdandriyal7/darknet-to-tensorflow-to-tensorflowlite-b783d55b106a).