# Convert custom yolo weights to tflite?

Tags: tensorflow, yolo

I have trained some custom dataset on yolov4 using darknet tiny cfg.

Now I have three files:

```
classes.names  
yolov4-tiny-custom.cfg
yolov4-tiny-custom.weights
```

In order to implement yolo object detection to flutter apps I need to convert these files to:

```
 .tflite and .txt
```

My total classes numbers are 54

How can I convert them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61585139/how-can-i-convert-yolo-weights-to-tflite-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go from yolo darknet weights to savedmodel pb to tflite. Once you have savedmodel generated then use TFLiteConverter to convert to tflite,

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert

I have deployed custom yolov4 tiny model to android with repo below. It may help in your case.

https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite

This repo was not updated in some time. Has `coco.names` hardcoded so instead modify the `config.py` code to include your `classes.names`. This is the related issue to fix the problem,

[cannot reshape array of size 1665179 into shape (512,512,3,3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62406263/cannot-reshape-array-of-size-1665179-into-shape-512-512-3-3/64598514#64598514)